# ESP32 on custom PCB - not booting

Tags: pcb-design, esp32, led-matrix

I have been working on a project that uses an ESP32 board to drive a HUB75E RGB matrix (using the library from [mrfaptastic](https://github.com/mrfaptastic/ESP32-HUB75-MatrixPanel-I2S-DMA) ) . And as an extra challenge, I decided to try and design my own PCB for it.

The final PCB looks like this:
[image: pcb_front]
[image: pcb_back]

First of all, feel free to point out any mistakes I might have made with the design. Just remember that this is literally my very first attempt at PCB design, so please be gentle :)

Secondly... something is wrong. As soon as I connect the matrix to the assembled PCB, nothing happens. The ESP32 keeps the onboard LED (GPIO2) lit, and it looks like it never boots. When measuring the GPIO2 voltage, I am getting around 2.5V - which *could* mean that the ESP32 is continually resetting, and/or outputting a PWM signal on that pin.

Unfortunately, I am unable to troubleshoot this behavior - as soon as I connect a USB cable to the ESP32 board (so that I can see the serial output), the device boots just fine. And as far as I can tell, it really *boots* (going through the initial setup steps), so it does look like it was not booting before.

What I have tried in order to troubleshoot the behavior:

1. I assumed a power issue (the onboard trace for the 5V power supply to the ESP32 is 6mil), so I soldered an additional wire between the external 5V and the ESP32 5V pin. Same result.
2. I started tracing the HUB75 connector pins, and noticed that I had reversed two of them ( LAT and OE pins on the matrix side). Instead of LAT going to ESP32 GPIO4 and OE to GPIO15, I had LAT-15, OE-4. So I tried reversing them on the PCB as well. Same result.
3. I tried connecting the HUB75 connector pins one by one - the problem appears when I connect pin 15 (matrix OE, going to GPIO15 on the ESP32 board. So I tried moving that pin (GPIO15 happens to be a bootstrap pin for ESP32) somewhere else - I connected OE to GPIO33. Same result.

In the end, my PCB looks like this, and I am still facing the same issue.
[image: assembled_front]
[image: assembled_back]

Before I give up and restart the design from scratch, I was hoping maybe someone can point out something obvious that I missed?

If you need additional information, I would be glad to provide it. Also, you can find the complete Eagle files for this project (including a photo of the schematic and some images of the boards as "seen" by Gerber viewers) [here](https://github.com/bogd/esp32-morphing-clock/tree/main/pcb) - just note that they might not match this board 100% (I did make some changes to the design after submitting it to the PCB factory).

As per the comments, I am adding the schematic:
[image: Schematic]

Comment: How did u handle the GPIO0 pin of ESP32 ? when programming, it should be connected to gnd and when connecting to Vcc(3.3v) through a pull-up resistor the module starts booting up and running ur program.

Comment: GPIO0 is left floating. IIRC, it has an internal pull-up that should ensure normal boot in this situation. As for the schematic, it was under the github repo linked above (in both .sch and .png format) - I am adding it here as well. Thank you!

Comment: Perhaps check what you mr 5 V is doing - if connecting a USB causes it to start up then that points to insufficient power, since the data pins don’t do anything special as far as I know.  BTW 6mil power supply tracks are way too small, you need around 20mil depending what you’re doing.

Comment: @Frog - I suspected the same, and to test my hypothesis I added an additional wire between the 5V line and the ESP32. However, the problem persists... As for the 6mil track, lesson learned - the next iteration will have at least a 30mil! Thank you!

Comment: @Bogd Where’s the 5V coming from when USB isn’t connected?

Comment: @Frog - without USB connected, 5V comes from the external PSU, via the 5.5mm jack and the ESP32 5V pin. The PSU outputs about 5.17V.

Comment: @Bogd are you still getting 5V from it when the ESP32 is powered though?  What’s the current rating of the PSU?  And have you measured the drop across D1?

Comment: @Frog: yes, and yes. The 5.17V figure is with the ESP32 powered. The PSU is rated to 10A, which is way more than my setup normally uses. And the drop across the diode is around 300mV - but to exclude that as well, I have connected the diode bypass jumper.

Comment: @Bogd it still looks like a power supply problem.  Have you measured the 5V *and ground* at the ESP32 pins?

Comment: Yes - about 4.9V between the ESP32 board VCC and GND pins

Comment: Just to update on this - I have just received the next iteration of the PCBs (with multiple changes, the main one being a wider power supply track), and they work just fine. So it might have been a power issue - what I don't understand is why I was unable to fix it with the additional wire I added :(

@Frog - if you would post that as an answer, I will gladly accept it!

Comment: It looks like a power supply problem. Have you measured the 5V and ground at the ESP32 pins?

Comment: @Frog - I did measure, and posted the answerhere (unfortunately, the way the website orders the comments definitely does not make it easy to match replies to questions). I had around 4.9V between VCC and GND (both measured on the ESP board pins).

Comment: @Bogd, that was me posting my comment as an answer, as you suggested, but it’s been switched back to a comment by an admin :-). 4.9V seems adequate but I can imagine that it could dip well below that if power consumption varies significantly with time (probably at the microsecond level or below).  It’s not obvious why adding discrete wires didn’t solve the problem so perhaps there’s more to it than meets the eye.

Comment: Unfortunately, without better testing tools, it is impossible to tell how that voltage varies (just like it was impossible to tell what was going on with the GPIO2 LED). The good news is that I have learned something from this experience ("pay attention to the width of power traces!"), and the next iteration of the PCBs seems to work perfectly. Thank you once again, @Frog, for your help!!